# Алгоритм поиска Эйлерова пути c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, graph

У меня возникли проблемы с алгоритмом поиска Эйлерова пути. Путь выводит, но не верный, помогите, пожалуйста, найти в чём ошибка
Проверяю на следующей матрице:

```
8
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Прграмма выводит следующий путь:

```
5 7 5 4 6 5 4 2 1 3 2 0 1 4 7 6 4 2 5 3 1 0 2 1 0
```

А должна выводить:

```
0 1 2 3 1 4 5 6 4 7 5 2 0
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int deg(int** matrix, int n, int v)
{
    int deg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (matrix[v][i])
            ++deg;
    return deg;
}
int findStartVert(int** matrix, int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (deg(matrix, n, i) % 2 != 0)
            return i;
    }
    return 0; 
}
bool checkForEuler(int** matrix, int n)
{
    vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (deg(matrix, n, i) % 2 != 0)
            ++count;
    }
    if (count > 2)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (deg(matrix, n, i) > 0)
        {
            dfs(matrix, n, i, visited);
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (deg(matrix, n, i) > 0 && !visited[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void findEulerCycle(int** temp, int n, int start)
{
    stack<int> s;
    vector<int> res;
    s.push(start);
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        int w = s.top();
        if (deg(temp, n, w) == 0)
        {
            res.push_back(w);
            s.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                if (temp[w][i]) {
                    temp[w][i] = 0;
                    s.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
        cout << res[i] << " ";
}
int main()
{
    int N, start;
    ifstream f("C:/Users/Documents/t.txt");
    if (!f) {
        cout << "Error, can't open file " << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
    f >> N;

    int** matrix = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            f >> matrix[i][j];

    f.close();
    
    int** tmp = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        tmp[i] = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            tmp[i][j] = matrix[i][j];

    
    if (checkForEuler(matrix, N))
        findEulerCycle(tmp, N, findStartVert(tmp, N));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С самого начала - программа пытается найти вершину нечётной степени для старта пути, но такой вершины в этом графе нет.

А для цикла и не нужно, достаточно ненулевой степени.

[Рабочий код с e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_path) выдаёт один из годных циклов `0 2 5 7 4 6 5 4 1 3 2 1 0`

Начало исправить так:

```
f >> n;
vector < vector<int> > g(n, vector<int>(n));

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        f >> g[i][j];  //matrix[i][j];
```

остальное с емакса без изменений

Comment: Проверку на нечетность я заменила на проверку на ненулевую степень, но все еще ответ не верный

Comment: Функция dfs не приведёна. В коде с указателями на матрицу такое себе удовольствие отлаживаться (я дошел до того, что в temp не обнулены элементы, которые уже в стеке, и надоело). Лучше возьмите проверенный код с e-maxx

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось